# The remote name could not be resolved: 'dev.azure.com' when setting up self-hosted devops agent in Docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, containers, devops

When I run the command in a cmd prompt

```
docker run -e AZP_URL=https://dev.azure.com/myOrganisation/ -e AZP_TOKEN=myToken -e AZP_AGENT_NAME=myAgent -e AZP_POOL=myPool dockeragent:latest
```

What is causin this error?

The container starts running and starts the powershell script start.ps1 (obtained from microsoft's tutorial)
I get the error

```
1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent...
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: 'dev.azure.com'
At C:\azp\start.ps1:32 char:12
+ $package = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64 ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\azp\start.ps1:33 char:1
+ $packageUrl = $package[0].Value.downloadUrl
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray


2. Downloading and installing Azure Pipelines agent...
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: address"
At C:\azp\start.ps1:40 char:34
+ $wc.DownloadFile($packageUrl, "$(Get-Location)\agent.zip")
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

Expand-Archive : The path 'agent.zip' either does not exist or is not a valid
file system path.
At C:\azp\start.ps1:42 char:1
+ Expand-Archive -Path "agent.zip" -DestinationPath "\azp\agent"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (agent.zip:String) [Expand-Arch
   ive], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Expand-Archive

3. Configuring Azure Pipelines agent...
Cleanup. Removing Azure Pipelines agent...
.\config.cmd : The term '.\config.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\azp\start.ps1:65 char:3
+   .\config.cmd remove --unattended `
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\config.cmd:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

.\config.cmd : The term '.\config.cmd' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\azp\start.ps1:48 char:3
+   .\config.cmd --unattended `
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\config.cmd:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I can reach the address with a browser but the set up can not.
What is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the result fo the following request, just paste the url in a browser `https://dev.azure.com/myOrganisation/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=win-x64&$top=1`

Comment: I tried it now and the result was a json containing count:1 and value with a creation date, version numbers and a few url e.g. download and info.

Comment: And I can add that using the download URL in the browser downloads the agent

Answer (score 0):

You need to base64 encode your Personal Access Token, please see the link below which contains a section called "Use a PAT".
From here you can see how to Encode your PAT using either Powershell or Bash.

Once you have done this replace the PAT Token you are using with the base64 encoded value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30470241)